# How to reduce this css code

Tags: css, sass

I am using this css code for my project and now I am planning move all of this to sass file I don't know how to reduce this code I am new to sass :( Is there any way to reduce following css code.

```
.push-bottom-0 {
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
.push-bottom-3 {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.push-bottom-5 {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.push-bottom-10 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.push-bottom-13 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.push-bottom-20 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.push-bottom-30 {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.push-bottom-40 {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.push-bottom-50 {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.push-bottom-60 {
  padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.push-bottom-70 {
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.push-bottom-80 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.push-bottom-90 {
  padding-bottom: 90px;
}
.push-bottom-100 {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [each](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#each-directive) loop.

**[SASS Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyodrq?editors=010)**

```
@each $i in 0 3 5 10 13 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
  .push-bottom-#{$i}
    padding-bottom: #{$i}px
```

**[SCSS Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ggvbar?editors=010)**:

```
@each $i in 0, 3, 5, 10, 13, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 {
  .push-bottom-#{$i} {
    padding-bottom: #{$i}px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try sass loops

```sass
@list 0 3 5 10 13 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100

@each $number in $list
.push-bottom-#{$number} {
  padding-bottom: $number;
}
```

http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while